# Pass a variable through a function parameter

Tags: php, variables

I'm trying to insert the output of "get_custom_field_value" into the id of the wp_table function.

My syntax must be wrong, because this isn't working.

```
 $menu = get_custom_field_value('menu-id', true);
 wp_table_reloaded_print_table( "id=$menu&use_tablesorter=true&print_name=false" );
```

Comment: Perhaps you'd have luck at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: I wasn't sure if it was php or wordpress custom field problem.  I guess wordpress.stack would have helped! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
$menu = get_custom_field_value('menu-id', true);
wp_table_reloaded_print_table( "id=" . $menu . "&use_tablesorter=true&print_name=false");
```

if this doesn't work yet, try to

```
print_r($menu);
```

to see, what menu looks like.

Comment: ahh, turned out to be a problem with get_custom_field_value.  Thanks for the help with the syntax!